# Python 3.6 assignment

Tags: python-3.x, loops

I'm new to python and I'm struggling with an assignment for a class I'm taking and cant figure it out.

The program should allow the user the option to quit, after each iteration of the loop. This is the part I'm stuck with

This is what i have so far and cant figure out how to repeat the statements after the user inputs `y`

```
first_name = input('Enter your first name:')
last_name = input('Enter your last name:')
phone_number = input('Enter your telephone number:')
carry_on = input('Continue (y = yes):')
```

Comment: There isn't a loop in here at all. Have you covered `for` or `while` in your course?

Comment: you need a loop.... what happens if the user continues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is

```
carry_on='y'
while carry_on == 'y':
    first_name = input('Enter your first name:')
    last_name = input('Enter your last name:')
    phone_number = input('Enter your telephone number:')
    carry_on = input('Continue (y = yes):')
```